# junction targets not found anymore

Tags: windows

I created a python venv with

```
python -m venv .\venv\myfolder
```

and it worked fine until today. Now it looks like something removed the junction targets

```
cmd
dir /al /s | findstr "<JUNCTION>"
<JUNCTION>     python [...]
<JUNCTION>     python3 [...]

powershell
dir
0 python ->
0 python ->
```

it looks like the junction targets are not found anymore.
how to check where the junctions are referring to ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: thought it's clear. added a comment that it looks like the targets are not found and I don't know where the installation should be as I have many python installations.

Comment: Try `FSUTIL hardlink list filename`

Comment: fsutil hardlink list python shows just the full path to the python link nothing else.E.g. .....venv\myfolder\python